# Angularjs performance of $scope.watch vs manual function call?

Tags: angularjs

Assuming I have a very complicated object where each key has very large nested structures for values. Each entry in the object (key, complex nested value pair) comes as a result of a call to some http service.

Performance-wise... is it better to....

1) In a service, scope watch the object for any new keys, then inside of it, call a function to do something.
2) After a successful http request, manually call functions that would have otherwise been in the scope watch function to process the new information.

I think the angular way is to watch, but if option 1 would cause a performance issue due to some constant watching, I would prefer to do 2.

What is the best performance way to do this provided that my object being watched could potentially have a large volume key/values?

Comment: Whats the use case for this? If you know when the object is going to be modified from the code, I would manually call it. `$watch` can be pretty hefty on resources depending on the app size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend creating a version on the scope and watching that. i.e.:

```
$scope.version = 1;
```

Then, whenever your code changes something about the object, simply increment the verion:

```
$scope.version += 1;
```

And finally, set your watch on "version" to respond to any changes.